# SQL Create Table with Partition Scheme result in blocking

Tags: sql, sql-server, blocking, database-partitioning

We are trying to create a physical work table to perform partition swap. While creating the work table, the DDL statement for creating a table is getting blocked with Partition Scheme is specified.

Question - Does the Partition Scheme result in blocking? Any way to not block the DDL statement?

Please note, while this statement is getting executed there are other SELECT and DDL operations happening on other tables using the same partition scheme.

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    Partition_Key SMALLINT
)
ON Partition_Scheme(Partition_Key)
```

Comment: what system? oracle. mysql, sqlite, etc?

Comment: Is it NoSQL?   Post your DDL

Comment: MS SQL. Added the sample code.

Comment: I wouldn't expect blocking unless something is trying to alter the partition scheme (or function) at the same time. What were the blocking participants and what resource is under contention?